# Putting Many dictionaries in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to create many dictionaries in a list to build a Data Frame.

```
 {'customer': 1.0, 'item1': 'apple', 'item2': 'milk', 'item3': 'tomato'}
 {'customer': 2.0, 'item1': 'water', 'item2': 'orange', 'item3': 'potato'}
 {'customer': 3.0, 'item1': 'juice', 'item2': 'mango', 'item3': 'chips'}
```

I would like to get these dictionaries to a list like this:

```
[{'customer': 1.0, 'item1': 'apple', 'item2': 'milk', 'item3': 'tomato'},
{'customer': 2.0, 'item1': 'water', 'item2': 'orange', 'item3': 'potato'},
{'customer': 3.0, 'item1': 'juice', 'item2': 'mango', 'item3': 'chips'}]
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Can you show code as well as the data structures?

Comment: `list.append(dictionary)`?

Comment: what is stopping you from doing that?

Comment: @SterlingArcher append you mean? add is a set method

Comment: My program output many dictionary  lines and I would like to aggregate these  to  a  list to create data frame with pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for something like below.Please read more on [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) and also on [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

```
   dict={'customer': 1.0, 'item1': 'apple', 'item2': 'milk', 'item3': 'tomato'}
   empty_list=[]
   empty_list.append(dict)
   print(empty_list)
```

> Your output looks like [{'customer': 1.0, 'item1': 'apple', 'item2':
>   'milk', 'item3': 'tomato'}]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store your dictionaries in list simply you can to use:

```
dict1 = {'customer': 1.0, 'item1': 'apple', 'item2': 'milk', 'item3': 'tomato'}

dict2 = {'customer': 2.0, 'item1': 'water', 'item2': 'orange', 'item3': 'potato'}
......

dict_store = []
dict_store.append(dict1)
dict_store.append(dict2)

print(dict_store)
[{'customer': 1.0, 'item1': 'apple', 'item2': 'milk', 'item3': 'tomato'},
 {'customer': 2.0, 'item1': 'water', 'item2': 'orange', 'item3': 'potato'}]
```

Comment: @htoohtoo nwe You can accept it if it helped, you need something more?